# informix odbc connection slow to open in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, odbc, informix

I have an application that takes a long time to open odbc connections (like 20 sec) also takes forever using arcmap and arcsde

but when I try the connection on the odbc data source administrator, it tests it really fast

Does anyone have any idea of what my be causing this?

btw the application works fine in another computer with another database

thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the Informix .NET provider as opposed to ODBC?  I had the same exact issue and using the provider (free download from IBM) proved to be the only effective solution.

Comment: Actually I started with the informix .net provider, and had even worst  issues with hanged connections, changed to odbc and things got fixed, but now I'm having problems with another server, not with the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ODBC administrator you can enable tracing. Then compare trace file from both slow and fast machine. If there is "fast" open from that machine using ODBC administrator and "slow" from your app then try other ways to open such connection. Try use it from other tool such as QueryTool (free trial), or create simple script in Python with win32 extension. In Python (I recommend Active Python which has win32 included) you can open ODBC with:

```
import odbc
import time

t_start = time.time()
conn = odbc.odbc('db_alias/user/passwd')
t_stop = time.time()
print('open: %.3f [ms]' % (t_stop-t_start))
cursor = conn.cursor() 
cursor.execute("SELECT FIRST 1 DBINFO('version','full') FROM systables;")
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print('[%s]' % (row[0]))
```

(note Informix specific version select)

Comment: I can't seem to trace using the odbc administrator, its not saving the log file :(

Comment: You should compare trace from your application on both fast and slow machine. Using Python code I provided you can check if opening ODBC connection it is different from opening in your application.

Comment: thanks, found out that was a mix of problems. The log backup script wasn't working and that it was a network problem between the second app server and the db server. The python script made it easy to test (still can't trace odbc with .net tho). thanks.